# can't add an imageIcon

Tags: java, exception, button, imageicon

i use this command to add an image icon :

```
iadd.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("add.png")));
top.add(iadd);
```

but i got that exception [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException]

Comment: Is `iadd` and `top` instanced?

Comment: idd -> jbutton
top -> jpanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the reason out, it was because i forgot to validate the imageicon after defining it :

```
iadd.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("add.png")));
validate();
top.add(iadd);
```

Answer (score 0):

The possibilities  to get nullpointerException  is `iadd` is not initialized.

```
iadd.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("add.png")));
```

or  in the line

```
top.add(iadd);
```

`top` is not initialized.

Comment: Can be on `top.add(iadd);` too

Comment: @SimonArsenault yes exactly

Comment: i had already initialized (iadd) as a button and (top) as a panel

Answer (score 0):

We need more information to be able to help you correctly. However make sure you instantiate `iadd` and `top`.

To instantiate, you normally use the keyword `new`. You should have something like that ABOVE your lines:

```
X iadd = new X(...); // Probably ImageIcon in your case
Y top = new Y(...); // Probably some kind of List (ArrayList, LinkedList, etc.)
```

Since we don't know the types, `X` and `Y` and only placeholders ;)

Comment: i had already initialized (iadd) as a button and (top) as a panel

Answer (score 0):

I am on the feeling that your exception is comming from getClass().getResource("add.png")

It's possible the resource is not found in the current package?

Comment: no it's not the resource because there is a resource error before and i corrected it.

Comment: What about just entering in the code in debug mode and see what happens?

Comment: i already made that... it stopped in "OutputStreamWriter" class specifically in that part :

 public void write(char cbuf[], int off, int len) throws IOException {
        se.write(cbuf, off, len);